# Limit of multivariable function- is the following solution legitimate?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the following limit:
$$
\lim _ {(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\ln (1+3x^2+9y^2)}{\arctan(x^2+3y^2) }
$$

Can I do the following? 
$$
\lim _ {(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\ln (1+3x^2+9y^2)}{\arctan(x^2+3y^2)}=
\lim _ {(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\ln (1+3u)}{\arctan(u)}
$$
and then use l'Hopital rule? (when $u=x^2+3y^2$)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Yes, it works well.

Comment: Yes, but be careful because you have hidden information in that $u$. If the function were different, it may not work.

Comment: Thank you both
@amcalde: Thanks !  will you please give me an example where such a substitution wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

with your substitution and L'Hospital we get $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+3u)}{\arctan(u)}=\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{\frac{3}{1+3u}}{\frac{1}{1+u^2}}=3$$